# Check if string is a potential match for regex

Tags: c++, regex

Basically, I want to be able to have a regular expression, such as `#[0-9]+` and be able to check if a string could match it. For example, if I am getting user input and they enter "#" this string is not a match to the regex, but could be if the user entered some numbers as well.

I know C++ has the `matches()` functions, but is there anything out there like what I am looking for? Or some way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean partial match (when part of string matches)? Like with `regex_search`? Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/F2Z8mQ).

Comment: Interesting question! +1 @stribizhev: I think he meant that there exists a suffix for the input which would allow it to match against the pattern.

Comment: regex_search isnt quite what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is more of the opposite. I'm looking to find out whether a string is a partial match for the regex.
In the example above, "#" isnt a full match for the regex, but it is a partial match as it begins with a "#", but more importantly has the potential to be a full match if more characters are added. "#a" isnt a partial match as adding more characters will not make it a full match.

Comment: @Pottsiex5: partial match is a bit vague... Is my definition correct?

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by "there exists a suffix for the input"?

Comment: @Pottsiex5: Do you mean you want to match `#` with `#[0-9]+`? No, it is not possible. For that, you need to create a special pattern that will allow no digits after `#`, like `#[0-9]*`. And use `regex_search`. Or discard regex at all if it does not suit you.

Comment: @Pottsiex5: The pattern below will pass any string with a "#" and one or more numbers after it. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @Pottsiex5 Why don't you just search whether your string begins with '#' and if it does use `regex_search` on the full string. You have a match if the search matches at the beginning.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: that wouldn't solve the problem. what if the input is `#a`.

Comment: I *think* you could write a custom regex engine (by modifying the original one) that solves this task, but I've never seen such a beast. And it has actually good real-life use cases - to literally check if the input is so far correct - "please keep on typing".

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes? In that case the potential match (searching for `#`) will succeed but the `regex_search` for `#[0-9]+` will fail as it doesn't even match. In the case of `#a#213` as input the `regex_search` will match yet the position (see `std::match_results`) isn't at the beginning. It's up to `Pottsiex5` whether to accept this as match or not.

Comment: Im am working on the assumption that I will be given one character at a time. So if the regex was (testing), and then I get the input "t" which given more characters could be a match. Then given the input "e", "te" given more characters could be a match, so I keep reading characters until I know whether it is a match, or not. That is what I mean by a partial/potential match. I want to know, while the string I am comparing may not be a match now, if I added more characters could it be a match.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: True. But you've made a custom solution for *one* regex. What if the regex is different?

Comment: One more comment from me. "if I am getting user input and they enter # this string is not a match to the regex, but could be if the user entered some numbers as well". That's what my code does.

Comment: @Pottsiex5 I don't get the use case. What information do you hope to get from a "potential" match? As long as the string isn't a complete match it's still wrong. The only solution I can think of is to provide smaller versions of the regex manually. In the example you might try to match against `#` (as regex) and if this is ok against the next larger (and in this case final) version `#[0-9]+`. Maybe you might just want to rephrase your regex to `^#[0-9]*$` which will match `#`, `#<Number>` yet fail on everything else like `#a` or `##`

Comment: @SimonKraemer: You can give the user instant feedback. Is what he typed so far correct (but not necessarily complete)?

Comment: Can you explode your regex into a series or regexes and see if it matches the first one, then if it fails on the subsequent one it can give some indication what it needs to succeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** The following is a pretty naive approach, that is neither fast nor beatiful. Yet it gets the job done for simple regex. **I do not recommend using this without understanding what it does**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>


bool is_valid_regex_string(const std::string& rgx_str)
{
    bool bResult = true;
    try
    {
        std::regex tmp(rgx_str);
    }
    catch (const std::regex_error& e)
    {
        (e);
        bResult = false;
    }
    return bResult;
}

std::string create_partial_regex_string(const std::string& rgx_str)
{
    std::string par_rgx_str;
    for (int i = 1; i <= rgx_str.size(); i++)
    {
        std::string sub_rgx_str = rgx_str.substr(0, i);
        if (is_valid_regex_string(sub_rgx_str))
        {
            if (!par_rgx_str.empty())par_rgx_str += "|";
            par_rgx_str += "(" + sub_rgx_str + ")";
        }
    }
    //return par_rgx_str;
    return "^" + par_rgx_str + "$";
}


void testPartialRegex(const std::string& rgx, const std::string& str)
{
    std::string partialRegexString = create_partial_regex_string(rgx);
    std::regex partRegex(partialRegexString);
    std::cout << "\tTESTING \"" << str << "\" against \"" << partialRegexString << "\" :" << std::endl;

    std::smatch base_match;
    std::cout << "\t\t-> " << (std::regex_match(str, partRegex) ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
}

void test(const std::string& str)
{
    std::cout << "\n###########################################\nTESTING \"" << str << "\"\n" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= str.size(); i++)
    {
        testPartialRegex("#[0-9]+", str.substr(0, i));
    }
    std::cout << "\n###########################################\n" << std::endl;

}



int main()
{

    test("#123456");    
    test("#12a3456");    
    test("#b");    
    test("123456");    
    test("##");    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
###########################################
TESTING "#123456"

        TESTING "#" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#1" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#12" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#123" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#1234" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#12345" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#123456" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true

###########################################


###########################################
TESTING "#12a3456"

        TESTING "#" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#1" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#12" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#12a" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false
        TESTING "#12a3" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false
        TESTING "#12a34" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false
        TESTING "#12a345" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false
        TESTING "#12a3456" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false

###########################################


###########################################
TESTING "#b"

        TESTING "#" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "#b" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false

###########################################


###########################################
TESTING "123456"

        TESTING "1" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false
        TESTING "12" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false
        TESTING "123" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false
        TESTING "1234" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false
        TESTING "12345" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false
        TESTING "123456" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false

###########################################


###########################################
TESTING "##"

        TESTING "#" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> true
        TESTING "##" against "^(#)|(#[0-9])|(#[0-9]+)$" :
                -> false

###########################################
```

Comment: going back and forth between upvoting this and not vote it... It gets the job done, but... you know...

Comment: Since an approximate, ugly solution (but working for the most part) is still better than no solution at all, you get my vote...

Comment: I guess storing the expanded regex would be the right way to use this solution in real life, to decrease the performance impact...

Comment: Like you said, its not pretty, but it gets the job done and it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/introduction_and_overview.html), which already implements [Partial Matches](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/partial_matches.html).

> When used it indicates that partial as well as full matches should be found. A **partial match** is one that matched **one or more characters at the end of the text input**, but did not match all of the regular expression (although it may have done so had more input been available).

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


int main  () {
    string subject = "#";
    string pattern = "#[0-9]+";


    const regex e(pattern);
    if (regex_match(subject, e, match_partial)) {
        cout << subject << " \tMATCHES\t " << pattern << endl;
    } else {
        cout << subject << " \tDOESN'T MATCH\t " << pattern << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/PFJNUL66673)</kbd>

Comment: **Note:** PCRE also supports it with [PCRE_PARTIAL](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2partial.html)

Answer (score -6):

The following code checks for you whether a string will match an expression with a "#" in the beginning and followed by one or more numbers...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string str;
    while (true) {
        cin >> str;
        regex pat{ "(#[[:d:]]+)" };
        bool match = regex_search(str, pat);
        cout << (match ? "Matched" : "Not matched") << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mistunderstood the task.

Comment: I am pretty sure you could have told me without the downvote. If my new answer is what Pottsiex5 is looking for, kindly remove the downvote please.

Comment: Does the current answer show good understanding of the question?

Comment: What is your understanding of the question?

Comment: You answering the example literally, instead of answering the actual question: Given a regex and a string, is it possible to find out if the string could potentially match the regex if it is appended by the right characters?

Comment: And downvotes are for wrong answers. Hence the downvotes you are receiving.

Comment: This isnt quite what Im looking for. I am looking for a generic solution, rather than a solution specific to a particular regex.

Comment: The downvotes are justified here - and constant moaning about them will actually result in more.